# Need to store html date input in JS var

Tags: javascript, html

I need help with JS and html. I need to store `<input type = "date" id = "date">` in JS var. If you try to store the date in simple var and try to print it instead of your chosen date you get printed "undefined" :

```
$("#printDate").click(function(){
   var dateVar = ($("#date").val());
    $("#results").append("<p>" + dateVar + "</p>")
});
```

If you try to store the date in the `dateVar` using `new Date()` you get printed "Invalid date": [image]

```
$("#printDate").click(function(){
   var dateVar =  new Date($("#date").val());
    $("#results").append("<p>" + dateVar + "</p>")
});
```

Thank you for any kind of help!

upd: full page code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">`</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <input type="date" id = "dateInput">
    <button id = "printDate">PrintDate</button>

           <script>
        $("#printDate").click(function(){
           var dateVar =  new Date($("#date").val());
            $("#results").append("<p>" + dateVar + "</p>")
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you please paste full snippet of what's not working for you? https://jsfiddle.net/92w0yjtk/ it looks perfectly fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("#printDate").click(function(){
           var dateVar =  new Date($("#dateInput").val());
           $("#results").append("<p>" + dateVar + "</p>")
});
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">`</script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="results"></div>

    <input type="date" id = "dateInput">
    <button id = "printDate">PrintDate</button>

</body>
</html>
```

The only problem with your code is you are targetting wrong id i.e `$("#date")` instead of `$("#dateInput")`

Comment: Such a shame :D

Comment: @Keetch  don't worry this happens. :P

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> <div id="results"></div>
>
> <input type="date" id="dateInput">
> <button id="printDate">PrintDate</button>
>
>        <script>
>     $("#printDate").click(function(){
>        var dateVar =  new Date($("#dateInput").val());
>         $("#results").append("<p>" + dateVar + "</p>")
>     });
> </script>
> ```

You have a typing error.